# Cordova app in ios13 device behaves weird with click or swipe actions

Tags: ios, cordova, touch-event, pointer-events

I have a cordova app. I have written some custom code in file for swipe actions using touch events, mouse events which will identify the touchmove and swipe. I have a hamburger menu at the top left corner of my app. On clicking this will open a side panel with some animation. on opening the app in latest ios 13, first time click anywhere on the screen is having MouseEvent with x,y,screenX,screenY,pathX,pathY values as 0. this triggers the hamburger menu which is at the top left corner of app and opens the side panel.

Why is the first time click event on screen returns x,y values as 0?

This issue doesn't occur in Android device or iOS <= 12.0 version. Only observed in iOS 13.

On removing my code specific to touch, swipe events. Then this issue is not replicable.

I have another observation. As ios13 supports the pointer events, I have just tried to add code related to pointerEvent

```
document.addEventListener('pointerdown', function() {
console.log('pointerdown event');
})
```

This worked for me without removing any code related swipe.

Why there is such difference in the behaviour with the code.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your description, we also effected by this issue. Sometimes we experience "ghost" clicks on previous clicked place in our cordova app.
Only happens with iOS13, with both UIWebView and WKWebView. 
Seems pointerdown eventlistener is a workaround for this.